# Why does the function VarianceMLE give a different result from Variance?

Tags: probability-or-statistics

Why does the function `VarianceMLE` give a different result from `Variance`?

And what is it in Mathematica 11.3?

[image]

Please see the picture above t665he MLE is 621 and the other is 665.

Comment: In Mathematica 11.3, ``<< Statistics` `` produces an error message and `Variance@data // N` gives 665.524

Comment: I'm going to guess that VarianceMLE is the maximum likelihood variance estimator rather than the unbiased one (assuming normally distributed data). The difference between the two is that `Variance` divides by `N-1` (`N == Length[data]`) while the MLE estimator divides by `N`.

Comment: And for future reference: please post copyable code in your question rather than a screenshot. This makes it much easier for someone else to copy your code and try things out.

Comment: Which book did you see this in? It looks like a scan.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just checked my guess in my comment and I was right. VarianceMLE is the maximum likelihood variance estimator (see, e.g. [here](https://www.statlect.com/fundamentals-of-statistics/normal-distribution-maximum-likelihood#hid5)).

```
data = {34, 56, 28, 62, 32, 90, 20, 10, 12, 35, 63, 78, 12, 25, 68};
Variance[data]
```

> > 13976/21

```
myVariance[lst_List] := Total[(lst - Mean[lst])^2]/(Length[lst] - 1);
myVarianceMLE[lst_List] := Total[(lst - Mean[lst])^2]/Length[lst];

myVariance[data]
myVarianceMLE[data]
```

> > 13976/21
> >
> > 27952/45

Comment: Thank you for your kind help, I will remember to post code next time.

Comment: Wolfram Research article also mentions a replacement for `VarianceMLE`: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/Compatibility/tutorial/Statistics/DescriptiveStatistics.html .

Answer (score 3):

`VarianceMLE` computes a biased, [maximum likelihood estimate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation) of the population variance.  `Variance` computes an unbiased estimate of the population variance.  It can be shown that `VarianceMLE` underestimates the variance of the population.

Let $\{y_i : 1 \leq i \leq n\}$ be a sample of $n$ values from a population.  The variance ([central second moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_moment)) of the sample is
$$  \sigma_y^2 = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (y_i - \bar{y})  \text{,}  $$
where $\bar{y} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n y_i$ is the sample mean.  This $\sigma_y^2$ is computed by `VarianceMLE`.

If $\sigma^2$ is the population variance, [with some work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Sample_variance), one can show that the expected value of $\sigma_y^2$ is $\frac{n-1}{n} \sigma^2$, so the sample variance is a biased estimator of the population variance.  We can make this an unbiased estimator via
$$  s^2 = \frac{n}{n-1} \sigma_y^2 = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i - \bar{y})  \text{.}  $$
This $s^2$ is computed by `Variance`.  From the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Variance.html) (in the Details):

"Variance[list] is equivalent to Total[(list-Mean[list])^2]/(Length[list]-1) for real-valued data."

The very sparse [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/Compatibility/tutorial/Statistics/DescriptiveStatistics.html) for `VarianceMLE` indicates that it is implemented in terms of `Variance`:

"VarianceMLE[data_] := Variance[data] (Length[data] - 1)/Length[data]"